# C# Loading assemblies dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, namespaces, using

I'm having an issue when compiling text into dynamic objects at runtime.

I wrote a simple piece of code to compile the text:

```
public class CompileFactory
{
    public dynamic Compile(String classCode, String mainClass, Object[] requiredAssemblies)
    {
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> 
          { 
             { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } 
          });

        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = true,       // Create a dll
            GenerateInMemory = true,          // Create it in memory
            WarningLevel = 3,                 // Default warning level
            CompilerOptions = "/optimize",    // Optimize code
            TreatWarningsAsErrors = false     // Better be false to avoid break in warnings
        };

        // Add all extra assemblies required
        foreach (var extraAsm in requiredAssemblies)
        {
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(extraAsm as string);
        }
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, classCode);
        if (results.Errors.Count != 0)
        {
            return "FAILED";
        }
        return results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(mainClass); ;
    }
}
```

This is how I am using the `Compile` method.

```
List<string> assemblies = new List<string>{"System.Net.Mail.dll", "System.Net.dll"};
dynamic obj = compile.Compile(fileText, pluginName, assemblies.ToArray());
```

As you can see I'm adding references to extra assemblies at some point. For some reason when I add `using System.Net;` to the text file, it will not be referenced and I get errors. The text I'm compiling is literally a .cs file saved as text. I thought of working around this by extracting the `using *` and adding them separately, however for when adding `System.Net.Mail.dll`, the metadata file cannot be found.

Has anyone experienced something similar? I really would like to just add the `using *` to the file and be ready with it.
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how you call `Compile`? I'd like to see the arguments you pass

Comment: @PhilippeParé `dynamic obj = compile.Compile(fileText, pluginName, assemblies.ToArray());` Assemblies is just a `List<string>{"System.Net.Mail.dll", "System.Net.dll"};`

Comment: You should add this to your post because it is very relevant to your issue, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `System.Net.dll` does not exist. You can check in which assembly a .Net type is by right clicking somewhere it is referenced and choosing "Go to definition". This will bring up a tab with the class definition "from metadata". At the top of this file, you've got a `#region` showing where this type comes from. In the case of a `TcpClient`, we can see this:

```
#region Assembly System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll
#endregion
```

Change your call to `Compile` with "System.dll" instead of "System.Net.dll" and it should work just fine

Edit/Clarification: It is not possible to get an assembly name from a `using` statement.

Comment: Sure, that would work for this one example. I would like a solution in which any type of reference to an assembly would be resolved. When only adding `System.dll` to the references, `System.XML.dll` is not added. Do you get where I'm going? Decide based on the `using *` calls which extra assemblies should be added while compiling.

Comment: Next to this `System.Net.dll` loads just fine, `System.Net.Mail.dll` does however not

Comment: you can't find an assembly required only based on a `using` statement. I recommend you put all the assemblies you need in the references

Comment: And how can I decide which assemblies are nessecary. Just hard-coding all required assemblies for all files is not only impossible but also not very efficient and code friendly.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. If you need to execute a string of code at runtime, I strongly recommend you know which assemblies are referenced. Especially if you are not the one writing the string of code (a user on a site)

Comment: Your thoughts on this are correct, users write code and I compile them. You can't tell me there is no way to decide which assembly is being referenced based on the `using *` statement. Visual Studio can find the declaration of it somehow, how can I do it programatically?

Comment: If you are missing a reference in visual studio, you would get a message like `The type or namespace name 'MyControl' does not exist in the namespace 'MyNamespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?`. If I where you, I would add options for the user to select assemblies to reference. you list them once and present the option to the user. Simpler, safer and easier.

Comment: var assembly = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("System.Net");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assembly.Location);

Comment: That won't help. First off, it's deprecated. Second, you wouldn't be able to pass a using statement's namespace there and get the assembly name from it. It is directly equivalent to doing `Assembly.Load`

Comment: @RobinVanCleef: you'll need to specify references somehow. `using` statements simply don't contain enough information. Assemblies can be located anywhere, different assemblies can contain the same namespaces, multiple versions of the same assembly can exist... If you're familiar with Linqpad, you'll see that its .linq files contain plain-text code, with a small xml header that contains referenced assembly paths.

Comment: @Philippe Paré It's not, I didn't add using statement and Load can't find the assembly.

Comment: [This method has been deprecated. Please use Assembly.Load() instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12xc5368(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know but in my case Load doesn't work but LoadWithPartialName does.

Comment: You are not facing the same issue as @RobinVanCleef

Comment: The code works now. It's getting the assembly from global cache. I don't even have the reference in my project nor "using". For example it worked for "MySql.Data" because I have installed MySql. While debugging I can see full details of the loaded assembly including version number, etc.

Comment: @PhilippeParé In the previous example I was referring to `System.Net.Mail`, when going to it's definition it says it is contained in `System.dll`. However when compiling, the reference to `SmtpClient` is missing somehow.

Comment: There could be more than one dll in global cache for the same partial name. This can be an issue.

Comment: @derloopkat Your solution is not working for me, this piece of code cannot find `System.Net.Mail`, the Assembly keeps `null`

Comment: @RobinVanCleef I took your code, only added a reference to `System.dll` and compiled successfully a class `Program` containing a reference to `SmtpClient`.

Comment: Are you sure there is a dll for System.Net.Mail ? or that's just a namespace in System?

Comment: Right, there is no such thing as `System.Net.Mail.dll`, it is a namespace in `System.dll`

Comment: @PhilippeParé I'm getting  `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SmtpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)}` when only adding a reference to `System.dll`

Comment: @RobinVanCleef do you have `using System.Net.Mail;` ?

Comment: @PhilippeParé No, forgot it, VS wasn't notifying me however. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't need "using". It's the same problem we had earlier, the assembly is system.dll. Just go to ObjectBrowser window in Visual Studio and look for "System.Net.Mail"  , if you don't see the assembly full path at the bottom, then go to System.Net and then System.